# why is the data not getting passed through the javascript to the php

Tags: javascript, php

i am using the following form:

```
<form id="dataForm" method="post">
  <h2 id="formheader"> Update Product Description</h2>
    <div>
      <label>Product Name:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="orginalName" type="text" name="Name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>New Description:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="newDescription" type="text" name="newDescription">
    </div>
    <div id="theSubmit">
      <button id="editDescription">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

and using the following simple php, which when used with `action=editProductDes.php` works...

```
 $Name = $_POST['Name'];
 $Description = $_POST['newDescription'];

 if($Name !="" && $Description !=""){
 $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_Description = '$Description' WHERE P_NAME = '$Name'";
 $conn->exec($sql);
```

and then when i use the following java script the data is not passed through and I cannot see why as I have a similar function and form where the JavaScript works fine, can anyone see why the data is not passing through?

```
function editDescription(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name = document.getElementById("orginalName");
    var Description = document.getElementById("newDescription");

    var data_seen = false;
        // this is a flag to record whether any data has been seen. Used in the guard ofthe alert statement.
    if (name.value !="" && Description.value !="" ){
        data_seen = true;
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editDescription.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&Description=" + Description.value);
    }
    if (!data_seen) {
        alert("please enter some data");
    }
   }

submitButton = document.getElementById("editDescription");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", editDescription);
```

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: I dont get any error in the console or anything, the data is just not passing through when the javascript is run to the php page for the sql to run

Comment: first change editDescription.PHP to editDescription.php  and in php file 

$Description = $_POST['newDescription'];  to $Description = $_POST['Description'];   . due this wrong param name you pass null value to SQL . and it will return null value error ?

Comment: injection attacks are common, really common. You'd do well to protect yourself against them, suppose `$Name` hold a value like `x' OR P_NAME LIKE '%'; -- `, that would make the where clause look like `WHERE P_NAME = 'x' OR P_NAME LIKE '%'` and update the entire table

Comment: Your `javascript` function is running or default `form` submitting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting to `editDescription.PHP` instead of `editProductDes.php`

Change the following:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","editProductDes.php",true);
```

You are also sending the data in your post under another name than you expect it to be in your PHP code (`Description` instead of `newDescription`) - change:

```
xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&newDescription=" + Description.value);
```

Comment: yes sorry thats where i have changed the file name, you are correct, however this has not helped the problem